# How can add in data of "file_put_contents" an array and a variable?

Tags: php, file-put-contents

i would to use `file_put_contents($filename, $data)` but i have to add a bidimensional array and a variable:

```
$array= array(
   array("a","a"),
   array("b","b")
  );

$variable= 1;
```

How can i add them in `$data` ?

Is possible to do this by not adding both in a string ?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $newArray = ['array' => $array, 'variable' => $variable];
 file_put_contents($filename, var_export($newArray, true));
```

1. `$data` should be a string, you need to convert array to string.
2. `var_export` would outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a variable.

Comment: i don't understand :( how can i add BOTH (array and variable) in $data ?

Comment: @Borja I have updated my answer. The `$data` should be a string, so you can only convert your `array` and `variable` to a string.